# Opening new Form after getting data from serialPort

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, deadlock

I have run into a problem while trying to open new form after getting some data from barcode scanner. The idea is to have a Main form with opened serialPort and reading data with DataReceived event. When that moment occurs I want to open new Form and pass that data to it.
(The ideal state would be to pass serialPort so it will be operative there too)

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string barcode = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new SetCallBack(SetText), new object[] { barcode });
        }

    }
    delegate void SetCallBack(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
            Form2 frm = new Form2(text, serialPort1);
            frm.ShowDialog();
            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
    }
```

It works fine once or twice but after that the controls freeze. When I change the code to

```
frm.Show();
```

It is working without problems (or atleast they are not visible). Am I getting some Deadlock there because of .ShowDialog()?

//Note that I also fetch some data from database which is not shown here, but it might also cause the problem

Someone advice me not to use DataReceive event and instead of that set up a Timer(~250ms) and check for ByteToRead property, but I ran into same problem.

I would also stick to the working version with Form.Show() but unfortunatelly I need that dialog to be modal.

If you have any thoughts where the problem might be, I would be really happy.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you closing the form, scanning a bar code, closing the form, scanning another bar code, closing the form and eventually it stops working? Or are you scanning barcodes while the form is already open?

Comment: @Matt Run the app, scan the barcode -> 2nd form open. Close the 2nd form, scan new barcode, 2nd form open, close it and scad new barcode.

Comment: That is really odd! I just created a simple WinForms app and opened and closed a form with ShowDialog without any issues. Can you wrap a try catch around everything in SetText and see if an exception is being thrown?

Comment: @Matt No exception throwed. It just stops at ShowDialog() and I can't even close that by close button. It seems that the app is going into freeze after some time I close the second form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling a show dialog you end up with a dialog result. This dialog result prevents you from creating another dialog until you dispose of it (as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You should either dispose it manually or place the dialog call in a using call

```
    private void SetText(string text)
        {
                using (Form2 frm = new Form2(text, serialPort1))
                {
                        frm.ShowDialog();
                }
                serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
        }
```

or

```
private void SetText(string text)
    {
            Form2 frm = new Form2(text, serialPort1);
            frm.ShowDialog();
            frm.Dispose();
            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
    }
```

I think the GC is supposed to do this for you when the dialog is not used anymore. But I'm unsure how good that works with a invoke.

**EDIT**
bit of a gamble but try this:

```
private object mScanLock = new object();
private void SetText(string text)
        {
           lock(mScanLock) {
                Form2 frm = new Form2(text, serialPort1);
                frm.ShowDialog();
                frm.Dispose();
                serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
              }
        }
```

Comment: Added frm.Dispose(); but it still freezes after opening it for 2nd time, or 3rd time if I am fast at closing the Form2 and scanning new barcode

Comment: Do you have to close the 2nd screen manually or does it close when the code in there is done running?

Comment: I am closing it manually. By clicking some button, or some of my own buttons doing some action and then calling this.Dispose(); All of these options result in the same issue

Comment: Made a edit, not sure if it works but could be a deadlock. A lock should resolve that

Comment: Thank you. Tried but no success. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. When I m trying to open Form3 in the same exact way it is working well.
Will try to reqork Form2 and edit/update if something changes.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else (still dont know where) but U made a good point abour disposing that object so I ll mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

Could be some kind of Deadlock since you use your serialport in Form2. 
Can you give a example what you do with the serialPort1 in your Form?
The fact that your Form freezes sometimes is also a good indication for that.

If it is possible for you please just hand the neccessary data to your second form.

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(text);
```

If this is not possible, you have to check if really all your methods are thread safe. (=> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)

Comment: At this moment I m just passing it to the constructor, nothing more. All code working with that serialPort in Form2 is commented.